# How to store codeigniter view file gmap to redis to make view display faster?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, redis, predis

I am currently using the Predis library for codeigniter. The redis server am using is version 3.2 the last stable and battle tested version.
I have no problem saving, updating and deleting the datas in the redis. But my current problem now is, How to make a view file load faster?

Currently, I have a view file that displays the google map, it is being rendered by javascript. Hence, from google's gmap code. Is there a way to make this page load faster ?, which data should I save to redis to do so? am I supposed to save the whole body of the html and render it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis can't make your view load faster, Google Maps uses a set of images and javascript to render the map (This is what makes an slow page loading), if you want to make this faster, use an image and link it to Google Maps site (Not embedding the map on the view).

Comment: do you have any sample to show?. I cannot visualize what image linking you’re trying to say

Comment: This is how make your link to be faster.
<a href="google-map-address"><img src="map-image.jpg" alt=""/></a>

Comment: what do you mean?...the map is rendered by javascript..i dunno what link are you talking about.. see this ? `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map`

Comment: If you want a faster loading page, don't embed the map.
Javascript and images make the page slower (And the cuestion is to make the view load faster).

Comment: but then the map am referring to contains dynamic data in the infow window of the markers in it..it cannot be loaded statically